# Switch between JSON / View in onPreResponse in Hapi.js

Tags: javascript, json, hapi.js

I am trying to send response based on the URL. Wanted to check if it is possible to check url and send response in onPreResponse. This is something I want to do.

```
server.ext('onPreResponse', function (request, reply) {
  if (request.path.indexOf('/api') > -1 ) {
     // Do nothing. Let the response go as JSON
  } else {
     // Send back html by populating json data into 
     // handlebar template
     reply.view('layout', request.response.source);  // Need replacement for this
  }
  reply.continue();
});
```

How to tell HAPI to use view for rendering

Comment: Why does this have to be within an `onPreResonse`? Any reason to not use the standard routing functionality (i.e a route with path `/api/{path*}`)?

Comment: That is a great idea. An example would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd need to see more code to understand what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to send result JSON back if the URL starts with /api or route the result thru Handlebars. I have about 100 methods which I want to share between API and Web app. So essentially, I want to say "if url starts with "/api",   then do  "return reply(result)" or return reply.view('index', request.respose.context).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, why cant you define two routes?

```
[{
    method: 'GET',
    path:'/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply.view('layout', request.response.source);
    }
},
{
    method: ['GET','POST'],
    path:'/api',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply(result);
    }
}]
```